# How to prevent a widget from expanding using QGridLayout?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I've tried setting `setSizePolicy` to minimum and it didn't work. Here's my main window widget:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.resize(const.SCREEN_WIDTH, const.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle(const.MAIN_WINDOW_TITLE)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.error_dialog = QErrorMessage()

        self.createMenu()
        self.addWidgets()

        self.show()

    def addWidgets(self):
        self.wadListLabel = QLabel("Wad List:")
        self.wadList = WadList()
        self.pathInputLabel = QLabel("GZDoom Path:")
        self.pathInput = PathInput()
        self.lostSoulLabel = QLabel()
        self.lostSoulPixmap = QPixmap("assets/lost_soul_sprite.png")
        self.lostSoulLabel.setPixmap(self.lostSoulPixmap)
        self.launchButton = QPushButton("Launch")
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pathInputLabel, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pathInput, 1, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.wadListLabel, 2, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.wadList, 3, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lostSoulLabel, 0, 1, Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.launchButton, 2, 1, Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.launchButton, 3, 1, Qt.AlignBottom)
        
        self.grid.setRowStretch(0, 3)
        self.grid.setColumnStretch(0, 3)
        self.grid.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        
    def createMenu(self):
        self.openAction = OpenAction(self, self.addWads)
        self.exitAction = ExitAction(self)

        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(self.openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAction)

        helpMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&Help')

    def addWads(self, wads):
        existent = False
        for wad in wads:
            foundItems = self.wadList.findItems(wad, Qt.MatchExactly)
            if len(foundItems) > 0:
                existent = True
                self.error_dialog.showMessage(f"The wad {wad} has already been added to the wad list.")
        if not existent:
            self.wadList.addItems(wads)

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())
```

How do I avoid this?

[image]

Due to the lost soul being in the same column as the path input label, the path input label expands and that's not what I want, I want to block that widget from expanding to the size of the image label. Is there a way to do that using QGridLayout?

EDIT: The height of the `self.pathInputLabel` at position 0, 0 expands due to the height of the `self.lostSoulLabel` at position 0, 1. How do I keep its height fixed and prevent it to expand?

Comment: your question is unclear, could you put a picture illustrating what you want to get

Comment: I've added a picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSF98.png, it's on the post.

Comment: That image is confusing (and that makes your post too), I don't understand, for example, what that red arrow indicates.

Comment: The "GZDoom Path" label is huge due to the size of the image on the right column. I want that widget to stay in the same size as the "Wad List" label, without expanding.

Comment: @EricsonWillians Insert an expanding vertical spacer above the label, or change the text-alignment of the label (i.e. AlignBottom). You might need to make the other label span two rows. Another approach might be to use two vboxes in a hbox, rather than a grid.

Comment: @EricsonWillians Your post is still unclear so I voted to close it, I will continue my way since you do not provide what I have asked, bye

Comment: @eyllanesc, I've provided aditional information. The height of the label component changes due to the height of the image on the right, I want to prevent that. There's blank space between that label and the other components, **it's height has changed** due to the height of the image. **It occupies more space than it should**.

Comment: @ekhumoro, thanks for the tip, I'll experiment with this other layout. Aligning the text of the label to the bottom will still look ugly with blank space left, so I guess I'm just using the wrong layout to start with.

Comment: @EricsonWillians Do you want the list-widget to expand upwards to take up the free space?

Comment: @ekhumoro, yes, that's the one that should expand. Setting the row stretch on the list row doesn't seem to make any effect.

Comment: @EricsonWillians I think this might be close to what you want: `self.grid.addWidget(self.lostSoulLabel, 0, 1, 3, 1, Qt.AlignTop | Qt,AlignHCenter)`. No need to change anything else.

Comment: @ekhumoro, haha, it worked. I'll study the addWidget method to understand better what you did. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @EricsonWillians Great! It makes the label span three rows, so the other widgets are free to expand more naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ekhumoro in the comments, the problem has been solved. Needed to add a `Qt.AlignHCenter` alignment as well.

[image]

```
def addWidgets(self):
    self.wadListLabel = QLabel("Wad List:")
    self.wadList = WadList()
    self.verticalSpacer = QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    self.pathInputLabel = QLabel("GZDoom Path:")
    self.pathInputLabel.setMaximumHeight(20)
    self.pathInput = PathInput()
    self.lostSoulLabel = QLabel()
    self.lostSoulPixmap = QPixmap("assets/lost_soul_sprite.png")
    self.lostSoulLabel.setPixmap(self.lostSoulPixmap)
    self.lostSoulLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
    self.launchButton = QPushButton("Launch")
    self.grid.addWidget(self.pathInputLabel, 0, 0)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.pathInput, 1, 0)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.wadListLabel, 2, 0)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.wadList, 3, 0)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.lostSoulLabel, 0, 1, 4, 1, Qt.AlignTop)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.launchButton, 2, 1, Qt.AlignBottom)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.launchButton, 3, 1, Qt.AlignBottom)
    self.grid.setColumnStretch(0, 3)
    self.grid.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
```